# Android 'crop' animation on a view

Tags: android

I am trying to build a custom animation similar to shared element transition on Lollipop, but to work with API 11+. My activity A will pass data to activity B, which will draw the same element as in activity A using this data. I'm ok up to this point. Then I need to animate the view, i.e. change the view bounds without scaling content. So if you imagine the full-screen view, I need to kind of crop it to about 1/10 of the size without scaling.

Also the view that I'm 'cropping' is NOT an ImageView.

Any suggestions how this can be done?

[image]